# How to access session variable in view ejs?

Tags: node.js, geddy

I'm a new user of node and Geddy.

How to access session variable in ejs view template?

I'm also looking for a good book, tutorial that can help me build a member area with Geddy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you upgrade to the latest version of Geddy (should be released tomorrow), you'll be able to access the session directly from the template. just use the `session` object from your view.

There aren't any books out there yet, but we have some examples and how toos in the Geddy wiki. The Geddy website was also just revamped to include 50+ pages of documentation to help get people started.

Comment: Tried it with handelbars <span>{{session}}..{{session.userId}}</span> with no success ;(